# Returning to previous window not working in Python Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am very new to Python and trying my had designing a GUI application.I have 3 classes in a directory of a python project, each one projects a different window of different size therefore I am using **window.destroy()** everytime before I call another class, however in one window, I have a back button but while trying to access the Menu() function an empty window loads up. Below are the codes of all the 3 classes login, menu and customerDetails respectively. Path being followed: Login-->Menu--> New Customer--> Back Button-->(Ideal result=Menu, result=blank window ).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk    
from frontend.menu import Menu

class Login:

def log(self):

    if self.username.get() == "123" and self.password.get() == "123":
        self.window.destroy()
        Menu()



def login(self):

    # Title Frame
    title=Frame(self.window, border=2)
    title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
    # Addng login form frame
    frame=Frame(self.window,background="#CCD5CC",
    highlightthickness=2 )
    frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)
    # frame.pack()
    # Company Label
    company=Label(title, text=" RAJENDRA INVESTMENTS :: GUWAHATI",background="#CCD5CC",
                       font=("Calibri", 18, "bold"))
    # self.company.insert(INSERT," RAJENDRA INVESTMENTS :: GUWAHATI")
    # self.company.configure(font=("Calibri", 18, "bold"))
    company.pack()
    # Adding Heading Label
    HeadLabel1=ttk.Label(frame,text="Login with your Credentials",background="#CCD5CC")
    HeadLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 10), columnspan=2)
    # username label
    Username=ttk.Label(frame,text="Username: ",background="#CCD5CC")
    Username.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(10, 10), padx=(10,0))
    # Adding a input field for username
    self.username = StringVar()
    e1 = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.username,background="#CCD5CC")
    e1.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=(10, 10),padx=(0,10))
    # password label
    Password=ttk.Label(frame,text="Password: ",background="#CCD5CC")
    Password.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(10, 10), padx=(10,0))

    # Adding a input field for password
    self.password = StringVar()
    e1 = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.password,background="#CCD5CC", show="*")
    e1.grid(row=2, column=1,pady=(10, 10),padx=(0,10))
    # Button
    b1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="Login", width=9, command=self.log)
    b1.grid(row=3, column=0,columnspan=2, pady=(0, 10))

def __init__(self):

    # creating a window
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Finance Maester")
    self.window.minsize(width=500, height=450)
    self.window.maxsize(width=500, height=450)
    self.window.resizable(0,0)
    background_image=PhotoImage(file="images/123.gif")
    background_label = Label( self.window, image=background_image)
    background_label.pack()
    self.login()
    self.window.mainloop()



Login()
```

After login leads to Menu

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from frontend.customerDetails import CustomerForm

class Menu:


def call_direct(self,key,value):
    print(key, value)
    if key=="New Customer" and value=="1":
        self.window.destroy()
        CustomerForm()
    elif key=="Old Customer" and value=="3":
        self.window.destroy()

    elif key=="Current Customer" and value=="2":
        self.window.destroy()


    elif key=="Search" and value.strip(" ")!="":
        self.window.destroy()



def menu(self):


    # frames
    frame1=Frame(self.window,background="#d5e1df")
    frame1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.25)
    frame2=Frame(self.window,background="#d5e1df")
    frame2.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.35)
    # search label
    search=ttk.Label(frame1, text="Search: ",background="#d5e1df")
    search.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=(10, 10), padx=(0, 10))
    # # Adding a input field for search
    search = StringVar()
    e1 = ttk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=search, background="#CCD5CC", width=27)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0, 10))
    # Search Button
    sb = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Go", width=15,command=lambda : self.call_direct("Search", search.get()))
    sb.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 10),)
    # Menu Button 1
    mb1=ttk.Button(frame2, text=" New Customer ", command=lambda : self.call_direct("New Customer","1"))
    mb1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0, 10), pady=(10,0))
    # Menu Button 2
    mb2=ttk.Button(frame2, text=" Current Customer ", command=lambda : self.call_direct("Current Customer","2"))
    mb2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(9, 10), pady=(10,0))
    # Menu Button 3
    mb3=ttk.Button(frame2, text=" Old Customer ", command=lambda : self.call_direct("Old Customer","3"))
    mb3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10,0))


def __init__(self):
    # creating a window
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Finance Maester")
    self.window.minsize(width=500, height=450)
    # self.window.maxsize(width=self.window.winfo_screenwidth(), height=self.window.winfo_screenheight())
    # self.window.resizable(0,0)
    self.window.configure(background="#d5e1df")
    # self.window.attributes("-toolwindow"=> 1)
    # self.background_image=PhotoImage(file="images/123.gif")
    # self.background_label = Label( self.window, image=self.background_image)
    # self.background_label.pack()
    label=Label(self.window,text="RAJENDRA INVESTMENTS :: GUWAHATI",font=('Calibri',12,"bold"),background="#d5e1df")
    # self.label.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.01)
    label.pack(side="top", anchor="w", padx=(50, 0), pady=(10, 0))
    self.menu()
    self.window.mainloop()
```

New customer form

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from frontend.menu import Menu
from frontend.installmentDetails import InstallmentDetails

class CustomerForm():

def redirect(self, value):
    self.window.destroy()
    if value=="back":
        Menu()
    elif value=="continue":
        InstallmentDetails()


def custForm(self):

    # frames
    frame1=Frame(self.window,background="#d5e1df")
    frame1.pack(side="left", anchor="nw", padx=(50, 0), pady=(50, 0))
    frame2=Frame(self.window,background="#d5e1df")
    frame2.pack(side="left", anchor="ne",pady=(50, 0), padx=(0,50))

    # frame1 blocks starts from here
    # block 1 starts here
    statement_file_no=ttk.Label(frame1,background="#d5e1df",text="STATEMENT FILE NUMBER : ", )
    statement_file_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W" )

    StFileNo=StringVar()
    statement_file_no_entry=ttk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=StFileNo, width=25)
    statement_file_no_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")

    date=ttk.Label(frame1,background="#d5e1df", text="Date : ")
    date.grid(row=0, column=2 , padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="E")

    datetext=StringVar()
    date_entry=ttk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=datetext, width=22)
    date_entry.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")

    hirer_name=ttk.Label(frame1,background="#d5e1df",text="HIRER NAME : ")
    hirer_name.grid(row=1, column=0 , padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")

    hname=StringVar()
    hirer_name_entry=ttk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=hname, width=73)
    hirer_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W" )

    Address=ttk.Label(frame1,background="#d5e1df", text="ADDRESS : ")
    Address.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")

    address=StringVar()
    Address_Text=Text(frame1,  height=2, width=55)
    Address_Text.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")

    # block 1 ends here


    # Back Button
    sb = Button(frame2, text=" Back", width=20, font=("Calibri", 12),command=lambda: self.redirect("back"))
    sb.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=(10, 30), pady=(20, 15), rowspan=2)

    # Submit Button
    sb = Button(frame2, text=" Continue",  width=20, font=("Calibri", 12),command=lambda: self.redirect("continue"))
    sb.grid(row=9, column=1,columnspan=3, padx=(10, 10), pady=(20, 15), sticky="e")

def __init__(self):
    # creating a window
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Finance Maester")
    # self.window.minsize(width=500, height=450)
    # self.window.maxsize(width=500, height=450)
    # self.window.resizable(0, 0)
    w, h = self.window.winfo_screenwidth(), self.window.winfo_screenheight()
    self.window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    self.window.configure(background="#d5e1df")
    # self.window.attributes("-toolwindow"=> 1)
    # self.background_image=PhotoImage(file="images/123.gif")
    # self.background_label = Label( self.window, image=self.background_image)
    # self.background_label.pack(anchor="center")
    self.label = Label(self.window, text="RAJENDRA INVESTMENTS :: GUWAHATI", font=('Calibri', 12, "bold"),
                       background="#d5e1df")
    # self.label.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.01)
    self.label.pack(side="top", anchor="w", padx=(50,0), pady=(10,0))
    self.custForm()
    self.window.mainloop()
```

In the class Customer when I try to call Menu if the back button is pressed, I get an empty window. I have no idea why.

Comment: Try to minimize the example, maybe you will find the bug. You paste a lot of code and i can see only 1 `print` statement, if you're new to python, it will help you to understand what's happening, what is triggered... Only fix i can tell is to replace all those `Tk()`, you just need one `Tk().mainloop()` in your project

Comment: The first problem is that you create an instance of `Tk()` more than once. You should have exactly once instance of `Tk`. If you need more windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.